# equalHeight on row and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, equals

I have a html structure with a lot of rows and columns. 
Now I want that all columns in the same row have the same height.

I have make a script that doing equalHeight. But this script put the same height on all the columns. Below you find the html and the script.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you for helping me!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div><!-- /column -->
    <div class="column">

    </div><!-- /column -->
</div><!-- /row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">

    </div><!-- /column -->
    <div class="column">

    </div><!-- /column -->
    <div class="column">

    </div><!-- /column -->
</div><!-- /row -->

function equalHeight(group) {
   tallest = 0;
   group.each(function() {
      thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
      if(thisHeight > tallest) {
         tallest = thisHeight;
      }
   });
   group.height(tallest);
};

equalHeight($('.row .column'));
```

Comment: can you fiddle that.. It may easy for to find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this script http://jsfiddle.net/mmSeU/2/

```
function equalHeight(group) {
$(group).each(function(i,eachrow) {
       tallest = 0;
                      $(eachrow).children('.column').each(function(j,eachcolumn) {
          thisHeight = $(eachcolumn).outerHeight();
          if(thisHeight > tallest) {
             tallest = thisHeight;
          }
       });
       $(eachrow).children('.column').height(tallest);
    });};equalHeight($('.row'));
```